# Avoid using dataframe name multiple times for addition in R

Tags: r, addition

I am adding a large number of variables in R, some of which have arithmetic operations, and hope to avoid repeating `Dataframename$` for every single variable.  Square brackets showed promise but I couldn't get them to work.  I don't want to use functions or loops, but rather make the code easier to read by removing so many references to Dataframename.

Example:

```
NewVariable = Dataframename$Var1 + 6-Dataframename$Var2 + 7*(Dataframename$Var3 + Dataframename$Var4) + Dataframename$Var5.....
```

for up to 50 variables.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use `with(Dataframename, ....)` or `attach(Dataframename)`

Answer (score 1):

In base R,

```
with(Dataframename, {
       NewVariable = Var1 + 6-Var2 + 7*(Var3 + Var4) + $Var5..... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes with piping-logic:

```r
library(dplyr
Dataframename %>%
mutate(NewVar = Var1+Var2+Var3...)
```

Answer (score 0):

an old solution is using 'attach'
`attach(Dataframename)`

this allows you to reference variables in Dataframename without the prefix, but it is generally not recommended as it can lead to ambiguity with functions that have the same name as variables of your attached dataframe.